# IMDB gem not working on Windows with Ruby 2.2 - Can't use Nokogiri 1.6.7.rc4

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, nokogiri, imdb

I am trying to use the [IMDB](https://github.com/ariejan/imdb)  gem on Windows with Ruby 2.2 but this gem seems to force using an older version of Nokogiri which is not compatible with my Ruby's version on Windows.

This is the message I am getting:

```
The bundle currently has Nokogiri locked at 1.6.2.1.
```

I do have installed the RC4 version.

Is there any way to force IMDB to use the RC4 version?
Or other solution I did not think about?

Comment: The actual version on [github](https://github.com/ariejan/imdb) uses already version 1.6.5. Maybe you could use this version. And maybe you can ask for an “optimistic” version constraint.

Comment: Please don't use salutations ("hello"), validictions, ("thanks in advance") or signatures. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion board.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution on Windows is to create a Virtual Machine with Linux and then install Ruby.

Windows has many problems with properly handling gems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is only an exercise but I would like to keep using Windows by now. 
I have been reading about possible solutions but I can not get it working anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

### Preamble and warning

This *solution* is only an ugly hack and I don't recommend to use it.

The best solution would be a corrected version of imdb-gem with a (possible) “optimistic” version constraint.

Disclaimer 2: I don't use bundler, maybe this solution does not work exactly as I show it. But the process should be similar for bundler.

### Source of the problem

The [gemspec of the imdb-gem](https://github.com/ariejan/imdb/blob/master/imdb.gemspec) contains the command:

```
s.add_dependency 'nokogiri', '= 1.6.5'
```

or in version 0.8.2

```
s.add_dependency 'nokogiri', '= 1.6.2.1'
```

If this would contain an optimistic version constraint like

```
s.add_dependency 'nokogiri', '=~ 1.6'
```

you could use the version you use (assumed there is no reason for this specific version).

### Hacking the gemspec

During `gem install` the gemspec is copied to a location like 
`[ruby-installation-path]/lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\specifications`.

Look for the file `imdb-0.8.2.gemspec` and make this change:

```
    if Gem::Version.new(Gem::VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new('1.2.0') then
#  Begin of Hack the nokogiri version
#      s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<nokogiri>, ["= 1.6.2.1"])
      s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<nokogiri>, ["~> 1.6"])
#  End of Hack the nokogiri version      
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<rake>, ["~> 10.0.3"])
```

Then try if your script works.

I tested with nokogiri version 1.6.6.2 and detected no problem.

If the version 1.6.7.rc4 works also I would recommend to ask for a change on https://github.com/ariejan/imdb and a new version of the imdb-gem.

Comment: There exists already an [issue for an optimistic contraint](https://github.com/ariejan/imdb/issues/76).